# check if a string contains a string

Tags: c

I am currently working on a C program where I need to check whether there is a string inside a string. The string may be mylog.txt.1 and I want to check that it contains mylog.txt and if it does do something.

In order to perform this I am using the following code

```
int logMaintenance(void *arg)
{
    while (TRUE)
    {
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *ent;
        dir = opendir(directory);
        if (dir != NULL)
        {
            while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
            {
                if (strstr(ent->d_name, fileName) != NULL )
                {
                    printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
                }
            }
            closedir(dir);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Failed to read directory %i", EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        SL_WU_SleepUSecs(2000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code doesn't seem to be working. For some reason it will just print mylog.txt and not include any of the other files that end in .1 or .2 etc. I've also tried using >=0 instead of != NULL in the if statement and this just prints everything even if it doesn't include mylog.txt.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: [;) example usage](http://ideone.com/jV9T6)

Comment: How is `fileName` declared and set?

Comment: Its a global variable char fileName[FILE_PATH_BUF_LEN];  and is set by fileName = "mylog.txt";

Comment: I'd propose that for debugging you log `fileName`just before the call to `strstr()` by `printf()`ing it out.

Comment: I have tried that and filename is the value that I am expecting

Comment: You might like to double check your test data, that is the names of the files in the directory you are scanning, and also double check or typos in the string assigend to `fileName`.

Comment: It was because the files I was expecting (ones ending in .1, .2 etc) were for some reason deleted on the server and I hadn't noticed. I assumed they were still there. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

ANSI/ISO C provides the `char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)` function, allowing to find a needle in a haystack. Use `#include <string.h>` to get the prototype. Are you sure you have the args in the proper order?

**Edit**: I had the haystack and needle in the wrong order, blush.

Comment: Its the other way round. Needle should be the second parameter and haystack the first. [strstr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strstr.html)

Comment: Are you sure you have the args in the proper order? ;-)

Comment: I have tried them both ways round when I try it the other way I get mylog.txt and on the next line a .

Comment: @Boardy I was referring to Jens' answer ... ;-)

Comment: Uh-oh, I goofed big time, yes, I had the parameters in the wrong order. Thanks for pointing out this mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You might have the parameters to strstr() the wrong way around. It's hard to tell from your description. Are you looking for fileName in ent->d_name, or the other way around?

The first is the string to search inside. The second is the string to search for.

Otherwise, try creating a test case with fixed data.

Comment: This file name is set at the start of the program and won't change during execution, ent->d_name is the name of the files/directories within a directory that I am looping through. ent->d_name should include the string filename

Comment: I've also tried reverting the parameters but then I get mylog.txt and then a . on the next line as if its two separate files its found